# Invalid expression term

Tags: c#

```
int hour = 10;
if (hour > 0 && < 12)
    Console.WriteLine("It's morning.");
else if (hour >= 12 && < 18)
    Console.WriteLine("It's afternoon.");
else
    Console.WriteLine("It's evening.");
```

Keep receiving an error

> Invalid Expression Term '<'

Preliminary search on the issue did not yield results. Hoping to learn why this piece of code is experiencing this issue and how I can avoid it in the future.

Comment: You evaluate `hour > 0`, but then evaluate `< 12`.  You need to put something before the `<`, like `hour < 12`

Comment: `if (hour < 12) Console.WriteLine("It's morning."); else if (hour < 18) Console.WriteLine("It's afternoon."); else  Console.WriteLine("It's evening.");`

Comment: What are you checking as `< 12`? To a human, it's easy to see you're referring to `hour`, the compiler on the other hand has no idea.

Comment: Maccettura, you caught it, spot on. Can't believe I missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the parameter in the second part of your conditions.

```
int hour = 10;
if (hour > 0 && hour < 12)
    Console.WriteLine("It's morning.");
else if (hour >= 12 && hour < 18)
    Console.WriteLine("It's afternoon.");
else
    Console.WriteLine("It's evening.");
```